# How create database using FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, code-first

I trying to use FluentNHibernate in my test project. The folowing code generate tables in existin database:

```
        var sessionFactory = FluentNHibernate
            .Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                    c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefaultConnection")))
            .CurrentSessionContext("web")
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SqlCommandFactory>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

It's works when database already exists. But how create database if it is absent?
The connection string to database looks following:

> Data Source=MAIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Magazine;Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect
>   Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Also i'm try using another method. Shown below.

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false)
```

In this case i get another exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Magazine"
>   requested by the login. The login failed.

I change connection string.

> Data
>   Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Magazine.mdf;Initial
>   Catalog=Magazine;Integrated Security=True

LocalDb would be the best option in my case. But as in the first case with SQLEXPRESS I again received an exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file
>   '.....\App_Data\Magazine.mdf'
>   as database 'Magazine'.

I'm used Code First for EF before and EF create database if it is missing. How can i create database using FluentNHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to replace

```
new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true)
```

with

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Pleace look at my changes in question. `Create(false, true)` also raise exception. In case with LocalDB it is `Cannot attach the file` and in case with SQLEXPRESS it is `The login failed`.

Comment: It looks like something wrong with you connection string. Try to connect to your DB using SSMS or something else